# Is there any way to return the thrown away part of the split operation?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a basic application which lets the user to share or continue their search status between sessions with # parameters in Javascript (I'm building this as a SPA so GET parameters won't always necessarily work).

In my app I could have a URI like: `/items#rarity=rare,common,uncommon&cost=ascending&category=primary`

If I wanted to check what state to set the cost filter in my react component, I'd want to extract `asecnding` and then check the ascending checkbox to set the state on page load.

If I use Javascript's split function combined with regex, I can capture all information on cost by doing:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.split(/cost.*&/);
```

Right now, this will obviously return an array in two parts the first being `/items#rarity=rare,common,uncommon&` and `category=primary` as the split function will split on the condition supplied which in my case matches the string from regex.

Is there any way I can capture the extracted string from the split function so I can then parse the cost string?

Comment: No, don't use `split` with arbitrary-purpose regexes. Just properly parse the parameter structure.

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKjZwN hope this works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>No way</s>. Oh, there is! Just wrap your regex in the capture group.

```js
var s = '/items#rarity=rare,common,uncommon&cost=ascending&category=primary';
r = s.split(/(cost.*&)/);

console.log(r[0]);
console.log(r[1]); //there is the "thrown" part
console.log(r[2]);
```

Comment: I've just done this as a final resort...was more of a 'is this possible question'...would have been nice to just grab the removed piece :)

Comment: @Alex see the edit!

Comment: Oooh, that's really cool!! Thank-you @nicael

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below

```
var x="/items#rarity=rare,common,uncommon&cost=ascending&category=primary";

console.log(x.split('cost=')[1].substring(0,x.split('cost=')[1].indexOf("&")));
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRyLmA